# mongodb: how to make selection

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I Have a mongodb with objects like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "7XXXXXXXXXX",
    "apps" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "e0d538e0df9a345e",
            "os" : "android",
            "token" : "f1zp-VSi7Ec:APA91bEAbfH8nMeVidkIjPrJ28WHRFDy-BhvKCQdDSdCYsylUzET9GjbPHjofCrr1NMQurinMCI4fuiF7VWNPXne-80op_h0MloK217kc1zKptdo9FTgAH5R932uDphcyB1xQ27-AFdR",
            "version" : "3.2.1",
            "build" : "8115680e",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1571740696818)
        }
    ]
}
```

How i can select objects older certain date *using timestamp*in my case, for example older 3 month?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB query for document older than 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591125/mongodb-query-for-document-older-than-30-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`$toDate`** operator in **aggregation** to do the desired operation,

> I hope you are using mongo version 4.0+

$toDate is supported in mongo version 4.0 and on

```
let selectedDate = new Date();
selectedDate.setDate(d.getDate()-30); //subtracting 30 days from today's date

db.collection("your_collection_name").aggregate({$unwind:{ path: "$apps"}},
    {$addFields: { dateValue: {$toDate: "$apps.timestamp" }}}, 
    {$match: { dateValue: {$lte: selectedDate }}},
    (err, result) => {
       //perform your desired operations
    });
```

**Explanation:**

basically, I am first unwinding `apps` array, which will result in having a separate document of each entry in `apps`.

Then operate on the `timestamp` field in each document, and convert it into a proper date with `$toDate`.

Then in the next stage apply your filter with `$match`.

**UPDATE**  (from comments):

as you are using mongo version 3.2 the above solution will not work.

then I think, you can opt for another approach here:

1. Query all your documents in this particular collection, **find the proper date** from the `timestamp` field.
2. **Update each document** with a new field which will now have the value of computed date from the above step, and save it.
3. I suggest you write a **migration script** for the above two steps.
4. Make sure **when inserting** a new document, you already add this newly computed date field.
5. Then you can have simple query like:

   ```
   db.collection("your_collection_name").find({"app.newDateField": {$lte: {selectedDate }}}, 
       { "apps.$": 1}, 
       (err, result)=>{

       })
   ```

Comment: Failed to execute script.

I use mongo 3.2.0 and i got this error when i try run this script:

Error:
TypeError: redeclaration of let selectedDate 
Details:
@(shell):1:5

Comment: whether there is a way do this on mongo 3.2.0?

Comment: unfortunately, this is production database, and i can not change or add any fields

Comment: You have a few options here...    **1.** you add a new field from the timestamp and use that for your calculations.

Comment: **2.** you update each document and change `timestamp` only to contain a date in ISO format. Then have a simple query as shown in above ans.

Comment: **3.** You just take out all docs and then convert timestamp to date after the query is run, then filter out the result.