# Mongoose findOne() with a value higher than a var

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So, I've been coding a bot on Discord. But when I tried to make 30 days auto-delete **Tags**, I been thinking that how do I find a document with a **Time Expired Date** in miliseconds that higher than current time.

```js
const autoDeleteTag = function () {
 const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime()
 const findTag = tagSchema.findOne({ timeExpired: currentTime })
 if (findTag) return findTag.delete()
}
setInterval(autoDeleteTag(), 100)
```

But I don't know if this the right code? Because I think sometime it won't delete. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query for document older than 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591125/mongodb-query-for-document-older-than-30-seconds)

Comment: `
random.create({ random1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 })
`
so I do this, and after 2 minutes, it still doesn't delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare dates (or values), you can you use the $gt, $lt etc. operators.

For example if you are looking for the older tags than current date:

```
tagSchema.findOne({ timeExpired: { $lt: currentTime } })
```

Comment: You can find more details in the documentation :)